# How to create users to access mapR cluster and be recognized by MCS?

Tags: cluster-computing, admin, mapr

How do you create users that can be 'seen' by the `mapr control system (MCS)` web ui?

Currently have a mapr installation running on 6 `CentOS 7` nodes and have one of the nodes (say node02) acting as an edge node for users to log into (using gnome desktop environment and `xrdp`). When using `system-config-users` on node02, can create users and groups, but when trying to assign properties to these these users/groups in the MCS (eg. setting permissions or assigning volumes) the MCS gives error that 'this user or group does not exist'.

May be misinterpreting the info, but [this](https://community.mapr.com/thread/9223) post from the mapr community forms as well as the official [documentation](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Managing+Users+and+Groups) seems to imply that users on any of the nodes used in the mapr cluster should be able to be configured in the MCS:

*'MapR uses each node's native operating system configuration to authenticate users and groups for access to the cluster'*.

However, as stated in the previous paragraph, this does not seem to be the case.

New to using mapr and any explaination of what is happening and how to correct it would be appreciated.

Comment: Does mapr not have a forum or documentation of any kind?

Comment: @Rob Not that I could find aside from what was in the original post (added extra info to original post of the docs that were found).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that users and groups for the cluster must have the same name, UID, and GID on **every** node in the cluster. You can't put them on just one. Would need to use a command like:

```
clush -a 'groupadd -g 677 mygroup'
clush -a useradd -g 677 -u 6771 myuser_0001
clush -a ‘echo "myuser0001:mypassword123" | chpasswd'
mkdir $MAPR_HOME/directory/user/myuser0001
chown myuser0001 $MAPR_HOME/user/myuser0001
```

Corroborating information can be found in the [docs](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/AdvancedInstallation/PlanningtheCluster-user-accounts.html):

> Any user of the cluster must be established with the same Linux UID and GID on every node in the cluster.